# glib in c++ on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c, compilation, visual-studio-2013, linker

I'm trying to compile a `C++` project that includes the `C` library [*SkelTrack*](https://github.com/joaquimrocha/Skeltrack) which uses `glib`

Now, I get a whole bunch of the following errors:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_slice_alloc referenced in function _pqueue_new   C:\....\pqueue.obj
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_error_new referenced in function _skeltrack_skeleton_track_joints_sync skeltrack-skeleton.obj 
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_mutex_init referenced in function _skeltrack_skeleton_init skeltrack-skeleton.obj 
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_mutex_clear referenced in function _skeltrack_skeleton_finalize    skeltrack-skeleton.obj 
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_mutex_lock referenced in function _skeltrack_skeleton_track_joints skeltrack-skeleton.obj 
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_mutex_unlock referenced in function _skeltrack_skeleton_track_joints   skeltrack-skeleton.obj 
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_once_init_enter referenced in function _skeltrack_skeleton_get_type    skeltrack-skeleton.obj 
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_once_init_leave referenced in function _skeltrack_skeleton_get_type    skeltrack-skeleton.obj
```

Link to *SkelTrack* code referencing `glib`: https://github.com/joaquimrocha/Skeltrack/blob/master/skeltrack/pqueue.c#L34

I must say that my understanding of the compilation process—especially on Windows—is quite vague, but here are some points of what I think is relevant information:

- I installed `glib 2.36` through NuGet.
- The unresolved functions have been in `glib` since earlier versions; so I don't think that's the problem.
- *SkelTrack* is compiled as `C89` because that's what VS likes best. I had to fix a few declarations that weren't at the beginning of the block.
- I'm not even including any part of *SkelTrack* in the rest of the project yet.

**EDIT**

- I have added the folder `C:[...]\packages\glib.2.36.2.11\build\native\lib\v110\Win32\Debug\dynamic` under `VC++ Directories -> Library Directories` This folder contains `glib-2.0.lib`.

**EDIT 2**

I have **uninstalled the NuGet `glib`**, downloaded `glib` for Win32 manually and added the `include` and `lib` to the project config (C/C++ Additional Include and VC++ Library Directories, respectively).

I got all kinds of syntax errors like:

```
C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'const'    c:\[....]\glib-dev\include\glib-2.0\glib\gutils.h   122
```

But they were fixed using [this tip](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2014-January/msg00011.html):

> In gutils.h lines 82 and 122, and in gstring.h line 129, change
>   "static inline" to "static __inline".

And now I'm back to the `unresolved external` errors.

**EDIT: ANSWER?**

I was forgetting to add `glib-2.0.lib`, `gio-2.0.lib`, etc. to

> Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies

Comment: Have you included the lib files into VS's project properties?

Comment: Other thoughts: 64-32 bit mismatch? CRT mismatch?

Comment: I don't think so.. I'm trying another route now. Without NuGet, that is.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar fight with Visual Studio 2015, and I managed to get the NuGet package working; here's what I did:

### Step 1 (Prerequisites)

- Install the glib NuGet package.
- Create a directory where you add
  [`glibconfig.h`](https://gist.github.com/tversteeg/ba848fad54a96754b64a316ca91b4968) (I added it to `lib\Glib23\include`).

### Step 2 (Project Properties)

- Go to the "VC++ Directories" in Configuration Properties and add the following to "Library References":

  ```
  $(SolutionDir)packages\glib.2.36.2.11\build\native\lib\v110\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\dynamic
  ```
- In "C/C++" add the following to "Additional Include Directories":

  ```
  $(SolutionDir)lib\Glib23\include
  $(SolutionDir)packages\glib.2.36.2.11\build\native\include
  ```

  The first line should be the location where you put `glibconfig.h`
- Now in "Linker" add to "Additional dependencies":

  ```
  glib-2.0.lib gio-2.0.lib gmodule-2.0.lib gobject-2.0.lib gthread-2.0.lib
  ```

You should be able to compile now, but the DLLs are still missing from the output folder so you can't run the program.

### Step 3 (Copy DLLs)

- In "Build Events"/"Post-Build Event" set the command line to the following:

  ```
  xcopy /y /d "$(SolutionDir)packages\glib.redist.2.36.2.11\build\native\bin\v110\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\dynamic\*.dll" "$(OutDir)"
  xcopy /y /d "$(SolutionDir)packages\libintl.redist.0.18.2.10\build\native\bin\v110\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\dynamic\cdecl\*.dll" "$(OutDir)"
  ```

Now you should be able to run your program without manually compiling glib.